# Copy and Insert Cells to Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I already tried recording macro and the codes I got from different forums but nothing's working. I want ot copy a range of cells in an open workbook where the macro is and insert it in an excel file i opened through Excel.Application. This means rows below will be moved down and won't be overwritten. Howevere what's happening is a blank row is just inserted and not the cells I copied. Here's my current code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:G22").Copy
WORxls.Worksheets("SheetSample").Rows("52:52").Select
WORxls.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Insert (xlDown)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if workbook is readonly and Sheet Protected or not (`Debug.Print` lines), then put a Break point (red dot) the line `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. Check what values of the Debug lines and are you able to manually edit the data in row 52. Did you have `On Error Resume Next` in this Sub? Comment it out and see if you have an error showing up.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:G22").Copy
With WORxls.Worksheets("SheetSample")
    Debug.Print "Workbook ReadOnly? " & WORxls.ReadOnly
    Debug.Print "Sheet ProtectContents: " & .ProtectContents
    Debug.Print "Sheet AllowEditRanges: " & .Protection.AllowEditRanges
    Debug.Print "Sheet AllowInsertingRows: " & .Protection.AllowInsertingRows
    .Activate
    .Rows("52:52").Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Some more explanation would be nice. Tell what wrong with the question code.

Comment: still the same happens... :(

Comment: Are these the only lines in your procedure that involves row insert/delete? Can you also confirm that `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:G22")` does not have an empty row at top?

Comment: Yes these are the only lines. No it does not have an empty row on top. I tried copying on the same workbook through `Selection.insert` and that worked however not on different workbook

Comment: WORxls.ReadOnly = False
ProtectContents = False
Protection.AllowEditRanges = Error (this dooesn't return boolean)
Protection.AllowInsertingRows = False
Any idea how I can solve this? I tried
    WORxls.Worksheets(ClientTab).Protect AllowInsertingRows: = True
but still didn't worked.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but from developer reference, you should use  `.Rows("52:52").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown`

Comment: What you are experiencing is that nothing is in the clipboard to paste, hence a blank row! Can't help more if we don't see the full code and those sample files.

Comment: I tried inserting the copied range on the same workbook and it worked correctly. I also tried pasting normally the range in WORxls however it was pasted as an image, maybe that's the reason why it is not inserted properly since in WORxls the range in the clipboard is treated as an image